# Searching binary tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, tree, lookup

Hi I'm having trouble getting this code working correctly. It seems to be jumping out of the stack when it recurses all the way down the leftmost edge of the tree. I just can't seem to figure this one out.

```
public static Node lookup(Node node, int lookupValue) {

        if (node == null)  {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (node.value == lookupValue) {
                System.out.println("Found");
                return node;
            } else if(node.left != null) {
                return lookup(node.left, lookupValue);

            } else if(node.right != null) {
                return lookup(node.right, lookupValue);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If this is not a binary tree then why only right and left node are being matched

Comment: apologies, it is indeed binary obv

Comment: Is this a bst or are the values in no particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return whatever is returned form the left sub-tree (if present) without checking the right one. A lot of the `else` branching isn't necessary when there is a `return` statement in the `if` block. Change as follows:

```
public static Node lookup(Node node, int lookupValue) {
    if (node == null)
        return null;
    if (node.value == lookupValue)
        // System.out.println("Found");
        return node;
    Node rval = lookup(node.left, lookupValue);
    // only return if found in left sub-tree
    return (rval != null) ? rval : lookup(node.right, lookupValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else if` are not correct you chould check the left and right everytimes:

```
if (node == null) return null;
if (node.value == lookupValue) {
    System.out.println("Found");
    return node;
}
Node found = lookup(node.left, lookupValue);
if(found != null) {
    return found;
}
return lookup(node.right, lookupValue);
```